# Calculating a magnitude

Tags: c++, magnitude

I have a hard time compiling this piece of code:

```
UMat dx, dy;
Sobel(GREY_IMAGE, dx, GREY_IMAGE.depth(), 1, 0, 3);
Sobel(GREY_IMAGE, dy, GREY_IMAGE.depth(), 0, 1, 3);
resize(dx, dx, Size(dx.rows, dx.rows), 0, 0, CV_INTER_AREA);
resize(dy, dy, Size(dx.rows, dx.rows), 0, 0, CV_INTER_AREA);
UMat mag(dx.size(), dx.type());
magnitude(dx, dy, mag);
```

Whenever I try it a get a response:

> {msg="OpenCV(4.0.0-dev) E:\opencv-master\modules\core\src\mathfuncs.cpp:151: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src1.size() == src2.size() && type == src2.type() && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_64F) in funct... ...}

I have no idea what's wrong with the code above. Dimensions are ok, all three matrixes are quadratic. What shall I do?

Comment: The error points to line 152 in your code. Is the code you're showing anywhere near there?

Comment: The error is pointing to an assertion line within the OpenCV library, which isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: The assertion which is failing is checking three things, that the images are the same size, same type and have a type of either 32 or 64 bit float. Your code is taking the depth from the GREY_IMAGE mat we can't tell from your code snippet what depth this is, but if it's not a 32 or 64 bit float then that could be the cause of the error.

Comment: Is there anything I could provide to make it more clear?

Comment: Oh guys, I'm so dumb. Just replaced GREY_IMAGE.depth() with CV_32F and everything works properly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it working. In my experience OpenCV assertion errors can be very cryptic!